# Is it possible to use a heightmap like Mathf.PerlinNoise();?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, perlin-noise, unity3d-terrain

I am relatively new to Terrain Generation in Unity, and am currently stuck in one place.  I have followed Brackey's tutorial on terrain generation, and in that tutorial, he uses something like this:

```cs
float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x, z) * 2f;
```

To manipulate the height of the terrain.  I also followed Sebastian Lague's tutorial on this.  This is where I am stuck.

I want to use Sebastian Lague's `Noise.cs` file that he created (can be found on his [GitHub](https://github.com/SebLague/Procedural-Landmass-Generation/blob/master/Proc%20Gen%20E03/Assets/Scripts/Noise.cs)) to manipulate the terrain height.

The reason is because this noise generator, rather than `Mathf.PerlinNoise()`, gives you a much better control over the texture it outputs.  The problem is, `Noise.cs` will return a 2D float array, while `Mathf.PerlinNoise()` returns a 1D float value.  Is there a way for `Noise.cs` to return a float value, just like Mathf's function?

`Noise.cs:`

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class Noise {

    public static float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int seed, float scale, int octaves, float persistance, float lacunarity, Vector2 offset) {
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[mapWidth,mapHeight];

        System.Random prng = new System.Random (seed);
        Vector2[] octaveOffsets = new Vector2[octaves];
        for (int i = 0; i < octaves; i++) {
            float offsetX = prng.Next (-100000, 100000) + offset.x;
            float offsetY = prng.Next (-100000, 100000) + offset.y;
            octaveOffsets [i] = new Vector2 (offsetX, offsetY);
        }

        if (scale <= 0) {
            scale = 0.0001f;
        }

        float maxNoiseHeight = float.MinValue;
        float minNoiseHeight = float.MaxValue;

        float halfWidth = mapWidth / 2f;
        float halfHeight = mapHeight / 2f;


        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
        
                float amplitude = 1;
                float frequency = 1;
                float noiseHeight = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < octaves; i++) {
                    float sampleX = (x-halfWidth) / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[i].x;
                    float sampleY = (y-halfHeight) / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[i].y;

                    float perlinValue = Mathf.PerlinNoise (sampleX, sampleY) * 2 - 1;
                    noiseHeight += perlinValue * amplitude;

                    amplitude *= persistance;
                    frequency *= lacunarity;
                }

                if (noiseHeight > maxNoiseHeight) {
                    maxNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
                } else if (noiseHeight < minNoiseHeight) {
                    minNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
                }
                noiseMap [x, y] = noiseHeight;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
                noiseMap [x, y] = Mathf.InverseLerp (minNoiseHeight, maxNoiseHeight, noiseMap [x, y]);
            }
        }

        return noiseMap;
    }

}
```

`MeshGenerator.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;

    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;

    public int xSize = 20;
    public int zSize = 20;

    int mapWidth;
    int mapHeight;
    int seed;
    float scale;
    int octaves;
    float persistance;
    float lacunarity;
    Vector2 offset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize everything
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    void CreateShape()
    {
        // Creating the grid of vertices
        vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

        // Setting vertex positions
        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
            {
                //float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * .3f, z * .3f) * 2f;
                float y = Noise.GenerateNoiseMap(mapWidth, mapHeight, seed, scale, octaves, persistance, lacunarity, offset);

                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                i++;
            }
        }

        triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }
            vert++;
        }
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        // Clear mesh data, reset with above vars and recalculate normals
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (vertices == null) return;

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;

        // Draw Vertex Gizmos
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], .1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Noisemap returns an array of floats in a map format. Just use x/y accordingly to pick out your float.

Comment: I understand the principle, but as I said, I am new to this, so would you mind writing this as an answer, possibly with modified code snippets?

Comment: im on a phone so no. Use it just like the perlin noise. Get from array [x,y] as its a float

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share your research effort.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, I would've had to put `vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y[x, z], z);`  Now I've already tried this, but I suppose visual studio bugged and did not save it properly.  Anyways, yes, I just needed to use x/y to pick out my float.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).